# How to talk between two terminal, one using Ncat and one using Nping?

Tags: terminal, network-programming, nmap

i have to start an Ncat server in UDP mode listening to port 1337 on one terminal

Then on the other terminal with ONE command Nping, i have to send 2 UDP packets saying the message : Reseaux_pour_ingenieurs_

For my first terminal i did : ncat -l -p 1337 -u

For my second terminal i tried : 
nping -c 2 --data-string "Reseaux_pour_ingenieurs_" --udp -p 1337
console answer : WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts pinged.

i also tried : nping -c 2 --udp -p 1337
console  : WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts pinged.

So i'm kinda lost on how to do this how do i send this while using only one nping command ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

you didn't specify the ip for your target

Try this :

> **nping --udp -c 2 --data-string "Reseaux_pour_ingenieurs_" -p 1337 127.0.0.1**

Comment: Hi, i tried and it said :Starting Nping 0.7.50 ( https://nmap.org/nping ) at 2019-10-12 21:37 Eastern Daylight Time, Skipping 127.0.0.1 because Windows does not allow localhost scans (try --unprivileged).Execution aborted. Nping needs at least one valid target to operate.

Comment: Re: apparently this is the good way, my computer just won't let me do it, thanks.

Comment: No problem ! Good luck for the TP2 :p